# Merge two DF with a columns that are somewhat similar PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames with two different name formats.
In the first data frame, I have First Name, Last Name(Eg. Jeff Robinson). The second data frame has the same names but in a different format Last Name, First Name Middle Initial(Robinson, Jeff D). Not everyone has a middle initial. This name format is considered to have the correct format.
DF1

```
Name
Dave Manno
Jane Shirt
Dhruv Patel
Richa Sharma
```

DF2

```
Sharma, Richa D
Shirt, Jane M
Patel, Dhruv
Manno, David
```

I need to find a way to merge the two datasets in a way where I can get the names in the first data and names in the second data to be side by side together. I tired merging it by the last names, but they are not unique and repeated. Eg you can have two people with the same last names.

Output:

```
Richa Sharma  Sharma, Richa D
Dave Manno    Manno, David
Dhruv Patel   Patel, Dhruv
Jane Shirt    Shirt, Jane M
```

This is what I currently have but not sure what to do after this:

```
df1['first_name'] = df1['employee_name'].str.split().str[0]
df1['last_name'] = df1['employee_name'].str.split().str[-1]
df2[['lastname','firstname']] =df2['Employee_Name'].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have these dataframes:

df1:

```
           Name
0    Dave Manno
1    Jane Shirt
2   Dhruv Patel
3  Richa Sharma
```

df2:

```
              Name
0  Sharma, Richa D
1    Shirt, Jane M
2     Patel, Dhruv
3     Manno, David
```

Then:

```
df1["tmp"] = df1["Name"].str.split().str[-1]
df2["tmp"] = df2["Name"].str.extract(r"(.*?),")
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on="tmp")[["Name_x", "Name_y"]])
```

Prints:

```
         Name_x           Name_y
0    Dave Manno     Manno, David
1    Jane Shirt    Shirt, Jane M
2   Dhruv Patel     Patel, Dhruv
3  Richa Sharma  Sharma, Richa D
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Do you have a suggestion if people have duplicate last names? For example, if the data frame has Dave Manno and Jack Manno.